# Pandas: remove duplicates based on substring

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have the following 2 columns, from a Pandas DataFrame:

```
antecedents        consequents
  apple               orange
  orange              apple

  apple               water
  apple               pineapple

  water               lemon
  lemon               water
```

I would like to remove duplicates that appear as bot antecedents and consequents, keeping only the first appearing, and thus obtain:

```
antecedents        consequents
  apple               orange

  apple               water
  apple               pineapple

  water               lemon
```

How can I achieve that using Pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `frozenset` by both columns and test duplicates by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
df2 = df[~df[['antecedents','consequents']].apply(frozenset,axis=1).duplicated()]
```

Or sorting values per rows in `numpy.sort`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['antecedents','consequents']], axis=1), index=df.index)
df2 = df[~df1.duplicated()]
```

---

```
print (df2)
  antecedents consequents
0       apple      orange
2       apple       water
3       apple   pineapple
4       water       lemon
```

Comment: You could use DataFrame.drop_duplcates() on df1 like this: ```df1.drop_duplicates()```

Comment: @Jonathan - unfortunately not.

Comment: Yes you can:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
  {'antecedents':
     ['apple',
      'orange',
      'apple',
      'apple',
      'water',
      'lemon'
      ],
   'consequents':
     ['orange',
      'apple',
      'water',
      'pineapple',
      'lemon',
      'water']})

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['antecedents', 'consequents']], axis=1), index=df.index)
print(df1.drop_duplicates())

```

Comment: @Jonathan - problem of your solution is get diferent order like solution in my answer.